# Making a URL call again with $.get

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
var url = "http://apple.accuweather.com/adcbin/apple/Apple_find_city.asp?location="+escape(obj.extraLocCity)+","+obj.extraLocCountryCode;
$.get(url, function(data) {
var us =  $(data).find('CityList').attr('us')*1;
var intl = $(data).find('CityList').attr('intl')*1;
var extra_cities = $(data).find('CityList').attr('extra_cities')*1;
var exist = intl + us + extra_cities;
```

If "exist" is "0", I would like to make the URL call again using a different "url" variable.  Specifically, using "obj.extraLocNeighborhood" in place of "obj.extraLocCity".  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Happy to provide more information if need be.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: So sorry.  JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this

```
var url1 = "http://apple.accuweather.com/adcbin/apple/Apple_find_city.asp?location="+escape(obj.extraLocCity)+","+obj.extraLocCountryCode;
var url2 = "http://apple.accuweather.com/adcbin/apple/Apple_find_city.asp?location="+escape(obj.extraLocNeighborhood)+","+obj.extraLocCountryCode;
$.get(url1, function(data) {
    var us =  $(data).find('CityList').attr('us')*1;
    var intl = $(data).find('CityList').attr('intl')*1;
    var extra_cities = $(data).find('CityList').attr('extra_cities')*1;
    var exist = intl + us + extra_cities;
    if (!exist) {
        $.get(url2, function(data) {
            // do something here ....
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  I think that might be close.  I'm trying to get it so if "exist" = 0, stop the function and go back up and try again with a different URL. Once exist equals 1 or more continue the script.  Not sure if that explanation helps or not haha

Answer (score 0):

Why make two calls when you can potentially do it in one? Could you add another parameter to your server handler to accept the neighborhood code in addition to the others and return both results and then handle results all in one shot?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  Unfortunately not.  It's one or the other.  Depending on where you are, sometimes one works and sometimes it's the other